# Edit History doesn't show custom reasons for closing

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, revisions-list, custom-close-reasons

I noticed that the Edit History doesn't show the custom reasons given for the Off Topic->Other reason.  Something like that should be in the Edit History.

This example should have a custom reason:

[image: No Custom Close Reasons Shown]